# How do I undo a bower change in Visual Studio Team Explorer using git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I added the Selectize client library using git.
Then I had like 45 changes in my tray in the commit screen.
I did not commit.
I right clicked the top level folder and chose undo changes.
Now it still says 43 changes to commit.

How do I get rid of all these added junk files and just go back to the state I was before I added this client file in bower.
This is what my Team Explorer window looks like now.

[image]

---

I just figured out while writing this to go to "Dependencies\Bower" and right click on Selectize (extraneous), right click and choose uninstall.
Now all those nasty added files are gone.

But I have this last bower file change left in my changes screen in Team Explorer.
If I right click and choose undo changes it still stays there. If I compare to unmodified version it looks the same.  Why is this thing still hanging around?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get rid of all these added junk files and just go back to the
>   state I was before I added this client file in bower.

You can discard the changes by git command directly:
In the root directly of your git repo, execute the command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Then no matter for the staged files or new added files (delete manually), all the changes will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there a way to do it from the Team Explorer UI?

Comment: Yes, **Undo Changes** option works with the same way in VS. You can double check again. Note: If you you want to undo all the changes, select the root directory of the git repo, then undo changes (as the example here https://imgur.com/a/nd0bs).